# Getting a string with white-space from user

Tags: c, string, whitespace, scanf, gets

I've received an assignment of making a dictionary that holds up to 2 definitions for each word, the definition must be able to contain white spaces.

I've searched and saw lot of examples of using gets, fgets, modifiying the `"%s"` operator to include several ASCII values.

But the problem is that now of them work for me, when the program should be getting user input it seems that is just skips the line - I tried both in Code Blocks an VS 2012.
here is the relevant part of the code, note that there are limits on string sizes `temp_word [81], temp_definition [201]` and that `words, definitions` are `char**`.

```
printf("Please enter word no.%d and how many difinitions will it have(1/2):\n", i+1);
scanf("%s %d", temp_word, &no_definitions); //gets word and no. of difinitons
words [i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(temp_word)+1); //memory is allocated according to length of the word, + 1 for \0 that is'n counted by the function
strcpy(words [i] , temp_word);

printf("\n\n%d, %s\n", no_definitions, temp_word); //debugging
printf("Please enter definition no.1:\n");
scanf("%99[^\n]s", temp_definitoin);
definitions_a [i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(temp_definitoin)+1); //memory is allocated according to length of the definition, + 1 for \0 that is'n counted by the function

if (definitions_a [i] == NULL) //must take malloc's failure into account (NULL!)
{
    printf ("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    goto exit;
}

strcpy(definitions_a [i], temp_definitoin);

if (no_definitions == 1)
{
    definitions_b [i] == NULL; //if only one definition is entered the second one will hold the NULL pointer
}
else if (no_definitions == 2)
{
    printf("Please enter definition no.2:\n");
    gets(temp_definitoin); //gets definition
    definitions_b [i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(temp_definitoin)+1); //memory is allocated according to length of the definition, + 1 for \0 that is'n counted by the function

    if (definitions_a [i] == NULL) //must take malloc's failure into account (NULL!)
    {
        printf ("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    strcpy(definitions_b [i] , temp_definitoin);
}

//}
```

Comment: Can you give any examples of expected input & how it should be treated?

Comment: word: is a word without spaces and up to 80 characters.
definition: can be a sentence up to 200 chars which can contain spaces.
they will be printed later by demand.

Comment: Truly getting a _string_ from a user is a problem as user input is typically `'\n'` (a white-space) terminated and not `'\0'` terminated.  The usual action is it to get user _line_ input (not a string) until a `'\n'` appears.  Suggest `fgets()`.  This gets a _line_ and appends the result with a `'\0'` making it a C string.

Comment: BTW `scanf("%99[^\n]s", temp_definitoin);` --> `scanf(" %99[^\n]", temp_definitoin);`   (add space, no s)

Comment: Strongly recommend never using `gets()`.  It is no longer part of standard C since C11.

Comment: gets() doesn't work for me! I don't know why, it looks like the program just skips it...

Comment: `gets()` does not "work" because of the left-over `'\n'` in `stdin` from `scanf("%99[^\n]s", temp_definitoin);`.  Avoid mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()/get()` in the same program.  In the long run, `fgets()` is best.

Comment: chux, thanks it worked!!!
can you explain/reference me on what exactly %99[^\n] and %99[^\n]smeans?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51824/discussion-between-chux-and-medvednic)

Comment: I'd like to point out that 'fgets()' also takes the '\n' character as part of the string

Comment: @TerraOrbis Refinement: _Both_ `fgets()` and `gets()` takes the `'\n'` from the stream (e.g. `stdio`).  `fgets()` saves the `'\n'`.  `gets()` does not.

Comment: @chux ok but I'd say it's irrelevant since ultimately gets() does not include it in the string. My whole point in bringing it up is that the inclusion of the newline could potentially mess with his parsing functions. I guess my word choice should have been "includes" rather than "takes".

Comment: @TerraOrbis I'd say what gets does is irrelevant in this case because you should just not use it.

Comment: @Brandin yes agreed that's actually something I meant to put in my comment but for some reason didn't. Ironically I used that exact same wording "should just not use it".

Answer (score 1):

BTW `scanf("%99[^\n]s", temp_definitoin);` --> `scanf(" %99[^\n]", temp_definitoin);` (add space, no s) –  chux